# When can a (max) heap be a BST?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, heap

Cheers, let's suppose we have a MAX heap which does not allow duplicate elements. Is it possible for this heap to be a BST ? Choose the right answer(s) below:

1. A heap can never be a BST
2. A heap is always a BST
3. A heap can be a BST if there is only one node inside it (root)
4. A heap can be  BST if and only if it has up to 2 nodes

Which one would be an appropriate answer ? I would choose (3) and (4), and my explanations for all I give as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To start off:

A **(max) heap** is a *complete binary tree*, in which every node's value is larger or equal to its children's values.

A **BST** is a *binary tree*, where every node has up to 2 children and every node's value is larger than all the values of its left subtree, and smaller than all the values of its right subtree.

1. The heap I thought of was just have one value, e.g. 8. Since it has no children, this tree alone is only made up of its root. This tree is complete and the root's values are larger that those of its children so it's a heap. This tree is also a BST with no children. So there is a heap which is also a BST.
2. This is of course false. Let max heap be:

[image: max-heap-but-not-bst]

Of course this is a max heap, but not a BST since 6 is placed to the right of 8.

3. I think this is correct, as I also explained in (1)
4. Up to two nodes means that we can either have 0, 1 or 2 nodes.

If we have 0 nodes, it holds.

If we have 1 node, it also holds, we proved that.

If we have 2 nodes, it also holds. Let a max-heap with 2 nodes. For it to be max-heap it must be a complete tree, so by definition the second node should be placed to the left of the first node (root). By definition of the max-heap, the second node also contains values smaller than that of the first node (root). This is also tree for a BST with 2 nodes. So it's correct.

(If anything is incorrect please point it out. Thanks!)

Comment: The statement is `A heap can be BST if and only if it has up to 2 nodes`, so it must work in both directions. You showed that if it has two nodes, then it's a BST. However, you did not show that if it's a BST then it has up to two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky! Let's dive into all options one by one.

From the options of your question:

### A heap can never be a BST

Wrong.
Since a heap with one or two elements can be a valid BST too. (see example from 3rd option)

### A heap is always a BST

Wrong. from your example it's clear, that heap sometime's can't hold the property of BST, specially Max-Heap.

### A heap can be a BST if there is only one node inside it (root)

Wrong. Since a tree with two child's too can hold property of BST.

Example -

```
              3
               \ 
                5
```

The above structure of node is BST as well a Min-Heap.

### A heap can be BST if and only if it has up to 2 nodes

Guess what!! Wrong, too!. Since a single node can be a valid BST as well as Max/Min-Heap.

Comment: The statement is `A heap can be BST if and only if it has up to 2 nodes`. Your counter example is not valid because a single node is included under `up to 2 nodes`. You will need to provide a counter example with at least 3 nodes that is also a BST to complete your proof.